# Как следить за объектом в unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как в `Unity3D` на `C#` поворачивать объект так, чтобы он следил за другим объектом по двум осям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для поворота объекта в сторону другого есть специальная функция: [transform.LookAt(obj.transform)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html). Вы можете сохранить значение по той оси, которая вас интересует и, после поворота, восстановить значение.